# Messing with toggle function when click outside

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm stuck with my jQuery "functions" (I know basics only).
So I'm working on a responsive website and when the user press an arrow icon → [>] (a#side-toggle), the menu (#header-toggle) slides out, and the icon slides on the left to stay visible, and the text changes to change the arrow → [<].

When I click again on this icon, the menu goes back to where it came and the icon is → [>]. Perfect.

In the first function, an overlay DIV is displayed, to avoid user to press on the content while using the menu. When you click on this overlay, the menu slides back and the overlay disapears. Normal. But the text doesn't change, it's stuck like that → [<]

When I click again on the text to show the menu, it changes to this → [>], and the menu doesn't show up (the function has returned to its original state actually). If I click again, the function toggles, as it should.

I need to fix this, the user should only press once on this icon to show the menu.

Clean my code if it's possible, because I think it's a mess too, haha

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HXEm/2/) !

The problem is in the JS, here's an extract:

```
$('#side-overlay').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#header-toggle").animate({ 
        left: "-200px",
        boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)"
      }, { duration: 700, easing: "easeInOutBack", queue: false });
    $("#side-handler").animate({ 
        left: "0px",
      }, { duration: 700, easing: "easeInOutBack", queue: false });
    $("a#side-toggle").text($(this).text() == '>' ? '<' : '>');
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The HTML and CSS would also be helpful. A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be even better!

Comment: @BrandonBoone : I updated my question, and put a link to a jsfiddle as you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `slide-overlay` `.click()` function:

```
$('#side-overlay').click(function() {
    //...
    $("a#side-toggle").text($(this).text() == '>' ? '<' : '>');});​
});
```

`$(this)` actually refers to `$('#side-overlay')`, so since the target is wrong, the arrow does not change.  You must remove `$(this)` and replace it with the proper target...

```
$("a#side-toggle").text($("a#side-toggle").text() == '>' ? '<' : '>');});​
```

[**See it working here:**  http://jsfiddle.net/4HXEm/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/4HXEm/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the issue.

The jQuery toggle method is triggered on the `click` event of the designated selector. That means if you manually "hide" or "show" the overlay and menu without going through this event you'll be out of sync with the internal state of the toggled object.

In other words, click on the arrow and the internal working of toggle will fire the hide event on the next click, however the user clicked the overlay which manually hid the elements. User then clicks on the arrow and the hide event is fired even though the element is already hidden.

Here is the code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HXEm/5/)

```
var side = $('a#side-toggle');
var overlay = $("#side-overlay")
var header = $("#header-toggle");
var sideHandler = $("#side-handler");

side.toggle(show,hide);

overlay.click(function(){side.click()});

function show(){
    header.animate({ 
        left: "0px",
        boxShadow: "3px 1px 11px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.45)"
    }, { 
        duration: 700, 
        queue: false 
    });

    sideHandler.animate({ 
        left: "200px",
    }, { 
        duration: 700, 
        queue: false 
    });
    overlay.show();
    side.text('<'); 
}

function hide(){
    header.animate({ 
        left: "-200px",
        boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)"
    }, { 
        duration: 700, 
        queue: false 
    });

    sideHandler.animate({ 
        left: "0px",
    }, { 
        duration: 700, 
        queue: false 
    });
    overlay.hide();
    side.text('>'); 
}
​
```

Comment: +1, However, your problem description missed it.  You rewrote all of his code into something much cleaner, while I merely found the root cause of his described problem.

Comment: @Sparky672 - Thanks for kudos for the re-write. To clarify my solution: I understood the incorrect "this" selector as you see I have eliminated that part of the problem through the re-write/code-cleanup. However, you'll notice I also eliminated the second issue as well. If you click on the Red Arrow, then the Overlay, then the Red Arrow again; you'll see that the slider behaves correctly in my solution. In the solution you have provided, the user would still be required to click the Red Arrow twice in the last step. This is due to the manual hiding of the elements via the overlay click event.